# SSIS Redirect on Error - Too many rows

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that imports a flat CSV file, there are approx 200,000 records in the file. I've set the table that the data imports into with a primary unique key of the account number. There shouldn't be any duplicates in the source data (application controlled - outside of my influence)

However there is 1 duplicate row in the CSV, however when i add the primary key it redirect 7k rows... these aren't duplicate rows it just appears to redirect a load for no reason?

[image]

If I manually remove the single duplicate row it works perfectly. There is nothing special about the data or the files, it should just import the data and redirect the error row.

[image]

Comment: Do you use fast insert at OLE DB Destination or regular insert?

Comment: fast insert yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to OLE DB Destination and fast insert mode used.

With fast insert mode, OLE DB destination issues `INSERT BULK` command and does insert in batches. If one of rows within a batch violates table constraints, the whole batch is failed and got redirected to Error Output. This accounts for strange at the first glance behavior - reject more than 1 row.

What you can do with it - depends on your goal and limitations

- If simply filter out consecutive duplicates - switch OLE DB Dest to regular insert mode at cost of significant performance decrease. Simplest way.
- If performance drop is not an option, and you need to keep it simple - use **Sort Component** at Dataflow and tick *discard duplicate rows* flag. Caveat - you do not have a control on which row will be discarded.
- If you need to implement some business rules on what data should pass - then you have to implement some scoring column and use it to filter rows. See Todd McDermid's [article on this](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.ru/2009/01/eliminating-duplicate-primary-keys-in.html).